# How to use/decode swift-encoded base64 string outside iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, base64, decoding

I didn't find a response in the search section, so I came here.

I've made some functions that convert images to Base64 strings, nothing far from normal:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker                             : UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info   : [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        let pickedImageBase64: String = (
            pickedImage
                .pngData()?
                .base64EncodedString()
        )!;

        NSLog("image base64: %@", pickedImageBase64);
        self.imageHandler(pickedImageBase64);
    }
}
```

Nothing weird, I pick an image from the camera get the PNG data, ask for it as base64-encoded string, I put a log of that string, and toss it over to the an image handler.

Inside the application, I can convert that base64-encoded string to images with no problem, at all.

However, when I upload that base64-encoded string to a server, or even when I copy what's in the NSLog entry, **I can't decode it using base64 command in Shell, or using any service in the web.**

Tried with our good-old-friend: `cat file.txt | base64 --decode > myimage.png`; but "it's damaged".

However, when I copy that string, hard-code it into another iOS App, and try to decode it, **works just fine**.

I hope someone can helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Likely the contents of `file.txt` is not precisely the same as the contents of `pickedImageBase64`. I would strongly suspect that your uploading code is corrupting your data, though it's also possible that the receiving code on the server is doing the corruption.

Comment: @RobNapier I'd think of that too, but I copy from the logs the encoded string, though.

Comment: have you tried reducing the file size ?

Comment: @LeoDabus No, I haven't.

Comment: try a small jpeg

Comment: Agreed; a very common corruption is truncation. Check `pickedImageBase64.count` vs `wc -c file.txt`.

Comment: @LeoDabus yes, it seems at some point my image got truncated... thus, useless.
Copying it from NSLog is beyond useless, as NSLog has a limit of 1024 characters.

Comment: @LeoDabus no, that's a different issue. I had solved some things with that one, for using the base64 inside the app :)